# How to SUMIF depending on another column's value and REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

I'm trying to use SUMIF and REGEXEXTRACT, i want to get a total sum of the description only where paid out is not blank and the description value needs to be multiplied by value in paid out so on the below example the only sums which should be carried out are 145.7417 x 4 and 437.8270 x 2 which will give me a total of 1458.6208

The REGEX to extract the value from description is "[0-9]*.[0-9]+[0-9]+"

[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

Just to let people know, i've solved this now and i was looking at the wrong function, i needed to use ArrayFormula

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(0+iferror(regexextract(B2:B, "[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+")) * C2:C))`